# Is there any software that I can use to determine whether matrix group cosets are equal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, math-software, gap, computational-algebra

Is there any software that I can use to determine whether matrix group cosets are equal?

For instance, if I'm working with the group $SL_{2}( \mathbb{F}_{p} [[t]])$ and I want to know if $a SL_{2}( \mathbb{F}_{p} [[t]]) = b SL_{2}( \mathbb{F}_{p} [[t]]) $ where $a $ and $b$ are $2 \times 2$ matrices.

Thanks

Comment: $aH=bH$ iff $a^{-1}b\in H$. You can compute $a^{-1}b$ and presumably $H$ is defined in a way you can determine if a matrix is in it or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/), that's what GAP does!

Comment: You're the best :)

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept useful answers ;)